# Turning off hotstring options

Tags: autohotkey

I was going through AHK documentation on hotstrings, and found the [Options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) section particularly interesting

The one question I have is about turning off options, for example:

> C: Case sensitive: When you type an abbreviation, it must exactly match the case defined in the script. Use C0 to turn case sensitivity back off.

There are no examples of how you would do this, so that is my first question
**How would you do it?**

That is, what are the steps and some code examples I could use to accomplish it?

As for the second question, one that is not as important
**Why would you do it?**

Comment: The options described there are for a single hotstring. To affect the behaviour of all or the followed hotstrings see [#Hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Hotstring.htm) (directive) and [Hotstring](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Hotstring.htm) (function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, there are two main ways of creating a Case-sensitive hotstring.

#### Method 1- Single use Options modifiers:

Stick the options between the first and second colons of the hotstring. Ex:

```
;Case Sensitive
:C:ROFL:: Rolling on floor laughing
:C:ICYMI:: In case you missed it
:C:TL;DR:: Too long, didn’t read

;Non case-sensitive
::atot::A Tale of Two Cities
::ctbc::Cry, the Beloved Country
```

#### Method 2- `#Hotstring` directive

If you have a longer list of hotstrings you want some certain properties to apply to, you can use this directive. The directive will apply to all hotstrings following it, which is why there exists options like `#Hotstring C0` that can turn off a previously declared `#Hotstring C`. Ex:

```
#Hotstring C
::ROFL:: Rolling on floor laughing
::ICYMI:: In case you missed it
::TL;DR:: Too long, didn’t read

#Hotstring C0
::atot::A Tale of Two Cities
::ctbc::Cry, the Beloved Country
```

(Both of these code blocks are functionally identical)

---

To answer your second question, if you meant why would you need to use the `C0` option, please see **`Method 2`** above. If you meant why would you use the Case Options in general, that would be a matter of personal preferences.